# resolve the following error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, web-services, ng-app

I am very dificulty to resolve the following error in my applications client-side using AngularJS:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbGWB.png)

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error generally indicates that you either forgot to include the requested file. i.e. no `<script>` tag for the file or there is a syntax error in the file that it is trying to inject.

Comment: Okay, I was able to solve the previous error.

Now, I have the status of the controller and service request ok, but at the time of printing the data from my web api on the server side I do not get the data in my index.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like angular can not inject module due to an exception - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr

It's hard to tell what it could be from your image.